# Help with simple AS3 code class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Here is my class file:

```
package com

{

 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;
 import flash.filesystem.File;
 import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
 import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
 import flash.events.Event;
 import fl.accessibility.CheckBoxAccImpl;
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import fl.controls.CheckBox;


 public class main extends MovieClip
 {
  public function main()
  {
   stop();
   trace("b4 fate")
   stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, preview)
  }
  public function preview(e:Event):void
  {
   if (currentFrame == 1)
   {
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, actions1);
   }
   else
   {
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, actionsother);
   }
  }
  public function actions1(e:Event):void
  {
   trace("b4 event listeners")
   l1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto2);
   l2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto3);
   l3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto4);
   l4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto5);
   l5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto6);
   l6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto7);
   l7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto8);
   l8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto9);
   l9.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto10);
   l10.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto11);
   l11.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto12);
   l12.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto13);
   l13.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto14);
   l14.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto15);
   l15.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto16);
   l16.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto17);
   l17.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto18);
   l18.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto19);
   c1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto2);
   c2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto3);
   c3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto4);
   c4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto5);
   c5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto6);
   c6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto7);
   c7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto8);
   c8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto9);
   c9.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto10);
   c10.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto11);
   c11.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto12);
   c12.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto13);
   c13.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto14);
   c14.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto15);
   c15.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto16);
   c16.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto17);
   c17.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto18);
   c18.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto19);

   trace("after rl")

   function goto2(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
    trace("after rl2")
    gotoAndStop(2);
   }

   function goto3(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
    gotoAndStop(3);
   }
   function goto4(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
    gotoAndStop(4);
   }
   function goto5(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
    gotoAndStop(5);
   }
   function goto6(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
    gotoAndStop(6);
   }
   function goto7(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
    gotoAndStop(7);
   }
   function goto8(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
    gotoAndStop(8);
   }
   function goto9(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
    gotoAndStop(9);
   }
   function goto10(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
    gotoAndStop(10);
   }
   function goto11(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
    gotoAndStop(11);
   }
   function goto12(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
    gotoAndStop(12);
   }
   function goto13(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
    gotoAndStop(13);
   }
   function goto14(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
    gotoAndStop(14);
   }
   function goto15(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
    gotoAndStop(15);
   }
   function goto16(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
    gotoAndStop(16);
   }
   function goto17(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
    gotoAndStop(17);
   }
   function goto18(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
    gotoAndStop(18);
   }
   function goto19(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
    gotoAndStop(19);
   }



   /*
   var myfile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("mytext.txt");
   var filestream:FileStream = new FileStream();
   filestream.open(myfile, FileMode.WRITE);
   filestream.writeUTFBytes("hello data");
   filestream.close();

   var myfile2:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("mytext.txt");
   var filestream2:FileStream = new FileStream();
   filestream2.open(myfile2, FileMode.READ);
   textbx.text = filestream2.readUTFBytes(filestream2.bytesAvailable);
   filestream2.close();
   */

   /*var loadname;
   var loadnamevalue;

   var testnow;
   for (var lo:int = 1; lo <= 18; lo++)
   {
   loadname = "cb"+lo;
   var testiffile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("cb1.txt");
   if (!testiffile.exists)
   {
   break;
   }

   var myfile2:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(loadname+".txt");
   var filestream2:FileStream = new FileStream();
   filestream2.open(myfile2, FileMode.READ);
   loadnamevalue = filestream2.readUTFBytes(filestream2.bytesAvailable);
   filestream2.close();

   if (loadnamevalue == "true")
   {
   this["cb"+lo].selected = true;
   }
   else
   {
   this["cb"+lo].selected = false;
   }
   }

   var current;
   for (var inc = 1; inc <= 18; inc++)
   {
   current = "cb"+inc;
   this["cb"+inc].addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, storedata);
   }

   var storage:Array;
   var writevalue;
   var nowname;
   function storedata(e:Event):void
   {
   for (var ninc:int = 1; ninc <=18; ninc++)
   {
   nowname = "cb"+ninc;
   if (this["cb"+ninc].selected == true)
   {
   writevalue = "true";
   }
   else 
   {
   writevalue = "false";
   }

   var myfile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(nowname+".txt");
   var filestream:FileStream = new FileStream();
   filestream.open(myfile, FileMode.WRITE);
   filestream.writeUTFBytes(writevalue);
   filestream.close();
   }

   }*/



   var loadname;
   var loadnamevalue;
   var varname;
   var testnow;
   for (var lo:int = 1; lo <= 18; lo++)
   {
    loadname = "cb" + lo;
    var testiffile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(loadname + ".txt");
    if (testiffile.exists)
    {
     var myfile2:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(loadname + ".txt");
     var filestream2:FileStream = new FileStream();
     filestream2.open(myfile2, FileMode.READ);
     loadnamevalue = filestream2.readUTFBytes(filestream2.bytesAvailable);
     filestream2.close();

     if (loadnamevalue == "true")
     {
      this["l" + lo].visible = false;
     }
     else
     {
      this["l" + lo].visible = true;
     }

    }


   }

  }
  public function actionsother(e:Event):void
  {
   trace("gotthere")
   backbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goback);
   function goback(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
    gotoAndStop(1);
   }

   var checkbox:CheckBox = new CheckBox()
   addChild(checkbox)
   checkbox.x=100;
   checkbox.y=100;
   //trace("start");
   var loadname;
   var loadnamevalue;

   var testnow;
   trace("1")
   loadname = "cb"+(currentFrame-1);
   var testiffile2:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(loadname + ".txt");
   if (testiffile2.exists)
   {
    var myfile2:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(loadname + ".txt");
    var filestream2:FileStream = new FileStream();
    filestream2.open(myfile2, FileMode.READ);
    loadnamevalue = filestream2.readUTFBytes(filestream2.bytesAvailable);
    filestream2.close();

    if (loadnamevalue == "true")
    {
     checkbox.selected = true;
    }
    else
    {
     checkbox.selected = false;
    }

   }
   else
   {
    //trace("doesnt exist");
   }

   checkbox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, storedata);
   var storage:Array;
   var writevalue;
   var nowname;
   function storedata(e:Event):void
   {
    nowname = loadname;
    trace(nowname);
    if (checkbox.selected == true)
    {
     writevalue = "true";
    }
    else
    {
     writevalue = "false";
    }

    var myfile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(loadname + ".txt");
    var filestream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    filestream.open(myfile, FileMode.WRITE);
    filestream.writeUTFBytes(writevalue);
    filestream.close();
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I keep getting this error when I click a button: `Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.`

Why am I getting this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: which line is causing the error?

Comment: @samuel it doesn't exactly tell me that....

Comment: that's weird, usually you get a stack trace with line numbers.  Try removing code until you find out which part causes the problem.  Or add tons of trace statements or use debugger.  There's way too much code in your sample for anyone else to find which line is causing the problem.

Comment: please try and refactor that code.  it's really painful to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` instead of `Event.ENTER_FRAME`. Because to using `Event.ENTER_FRAME` event, object must be added to stage.

Comment: Which instance do I replace it?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by running your code in the debugger.  Do you know what line it is failing at?  That should help you figure out what is null and work back from there.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things I noticed.

The listener for preview() will get called every frame (regardless of whether you call stop()).  This means that every frame you are calling stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, actions1); which will only add the listener the first time but should still be avoided as a best practice.

As for the error you are getting, the first thing to try is calling trace(l1); in your constructor.  If that outputs out something like "[Object Movieclip]" when you run it, then you are good.  If instead it traces nothing and gives an error, you need to make sure you have added a button to the stage and gave it an instance name of l1.  If it does trace what we expected then your code should probably look more like this:

```
    public class main extends MovieClip
    {
        public function main()
        {
            stop();
            l1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto2);
        }
        public function preview(e:Event):void
        {
            gotoAndStop(2);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Duplicate listeners aren't added twice; but I would not add them on every frame anyway.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out!  I'll update this in case anyone stumbles upon it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the debugger: File > Publish Settings > Flash > Permit Debugging